# Sharing TeX Folders, \input

Tags: input

I typically use an \input{pathname1} in the preamble that houses all of my various convenient definitions and commands that I use quite regularly.  I do a similar thing with \bibliography{pathname2} at the end of my document, where I have just one large .bib file housing all my references.  I find this extremely convenient when switching between various projects.

However, when trying to share a folder via DropBox for collaboration (or for myself for use on a different machine), this no longer works, as far as I can tell, because even though I keep both of those files on DropBox (in an unshared folder), the path name obviously changes per user.  I'm looking for a nice fix to this, that doesn't require me to copy/paste my "master file" into every project folder, because I don't want to make every edit twice.

Comment: you should not need the full path just as you do not need the full path to `article.cls` just use `\input{myfile}` and arrange that your dropbox folder is in the TEXINPUT path

Comment: I don't need, nor use the full path typically.  It's normally \Bibliography{../myfolder/Bibliography} for example.  Which works fine, even switching machines and using my own DropBox.  However it doesn't work well for collaborations.  One possibility I'd like is to create a dropbox link to the bibliography and somehow call and interpret that link correctly, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: That's still a full path - it is just relative, rather than absolute. You should only need `\bibliography{<filename>}`, if you arrange TEXINPUTS  correctly. On Linux, you could probably just link from `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME/bibtex/bib/` to dropbox, but that isn't an option on Windows, of course. (And I'm not sure it would work even on Linux, but if a link would work anywhere, it is probably there.)